# How to enter passive mode for FTP using Golang?

Tags: go

I am new to golang and am trying to connect to a server via ftp server using golang. But as the server requires me to enter in passive mode for me to connect with it. Could anyone please tell me how I can do that?

Comment: Which ftp implementation you are using (there is no standard one)? Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am using https://godoc.org/github.com/jlaffaye/ftp package to dial to the server. But I am not sure how I am supposed to make that connection secure and passive.

Comment: From a short look of the code it looks like that this library does passive mode by default and does not even support active mode.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am still not able to establish the connection with the server though. Is it possible to create a secure connection with this package?

Comment: A simple search for TLS in the documentation will likely answer this question. But, it does not make much sense to provide only snippets on where you fail when you don't provide a clue what you are trying to achieve in the first place: there is nothing known about the server and how one needs to connect to it and  you don't show any code so far.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I am not able to post the code due to privacy issues. I am trying to connect to the mainframe server via go. The mainframe server has a few more levels of security that we need to take care of. The mainframe server only accepts the file transfer via Explicit Passive mode FTP-S using TLS. So, when I use the client login function, it gives me the error of server requires authentication before User command.

Comment: Looking at the code I would say that this library does not support explicit TLS, only implicit. And as for the code: nobody expects you to provide your original code. In contrary, you should only provide a minimal version which demonstrates the actual problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [goftp](https://github.com/secsy/goftp) library, set activetranfers to false

```
config := goftp.Config{}
config.User = userLL
config.Password = passwordLL
config.ActiveTransfers = false

client, err := goftp.DialConfig(config, hostLL)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```